# A proof for the generalizated Brun's theorem about the summability of the reciprocal of twin primes

Tags: reference-request, summation, prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Please, can anyone prove or indicate a paper or book where it is proved a generalization for the Brun's theorem? That is: the sequence $(1/p_n)$ is summable, where
$p_{n+1}-p_{n}=k$, (for some $k\geq2$ even), and $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summability of reciprocals of twin primes follows from the estimate and partial summation:

> Let $N_2(x)$ be the number of prime numbers $p\leq x$ such that $p$ and $p+2$ both are primes. Then 
>   $$
> N_2(x) \ll \frac x{\log^2 x}.
> $$

An analogue of the above is

> Let $r$ be an even positive integer. Let $N_r(x)$ be the number of prime numbers $p\leq x $ such that $p$ and $p+r$ both are primes. Then 
>   $$
> N_r(x) \ll_r \frac x{\log^2 x}. 
> $$

A reference for this result is Corollary 3.14 in Montgomery & Vaughan 'Multiplicative Number Theory I' Classical Theory.

Therefore, the convergence of the sum:
$$
\sum_{p, p+r \ \mathrm{prime}} \frac1p
$$
follows in the same way by applying partial summation.

Comment: @ i707107: Can you give a reference that elaborate this idea on more details. The book you mentioned does not explain how one can prove that the generalized Brun constant is finite.